# Submitting publishing permission for review on Facebook

Tags: facebook, permissions

We are applying for App to use, publish action to allow us posting on user's wall. But we could not submit our review because it says "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

Please help us to fix this error.

Comment: Is the message correct?

Comment: I got very similar error. You need to test with your account where you are using publish_actions in your application. This permission will work for your account since you are the developer. But if you haven't tested this publish_action none at all, that is the message you will get.